# Classe - passagem por referência

Tags: swift

Considere o seguinte techo de código:

```
class Circle {
    var radius: Double
    init(radius: Double)
    {
        print("I'm initializing a new Circle instance with a radius value of \(radius).")
        self.radius = radius
    }

    deinit {
        print("I'm destroying the Circle instance with a radius value of \(radius).")
    }
}

1 var circle3 = Circle(radius: 42)
2 var referenceToCircle3 = circle3
3 referenceToCircle3.radius
4 circle3 = Circle(radius: 84)

5 referenceToCircle3.radius
6 circle3.radius
```

Uma vez que se trata de classes, a passagem é por referencia, correto? Ou seja, como `referenceToCircle3` é igual a `circle3`, ambas terão o mesmo endereço em memória, logo terça sempre o mesmo valor lá armazenado. 
Então por que `referenceToCircle3` (linha 5) permanece com o mesmo valor mesmo quando o `circle3` teve seu valor alterado (linha 4)?

Answer (score 0):

> Uma vez que se trata de classes, a passagem é por referência, correto?

**Resposta:** Correto.

*Classes* em `Swift` são [Reference Types](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=10) enquanto *Structs* são [Value Types](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ClassesAndStructures.html). *(posso explicar essa diferença em outra questão)*

---

> Então por que referenceToCircle3 (linha 5) permanece com o mesmo valor mesmo quando o circle3 teve seu valor alterado (linha 4)?

**Resposta:** Quando você invoca `Circle(radius: 84)` quer dizer que um novo objeto do tipo `Circle` será criado com outro endereço de memória e passado pra dentro da variável `circle3`, então se você quer alterar o valor da referência para um objeto faça isso diretamente nele.

---

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**é diferente de:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]